# Stock analysis and forecast using chaos theory

Tags: chaos-theory

Yesterday, I was going through an article in which the user had mentioned that he has used chaos theory to predict stock prices and ended up with 30% + profit.(I am not intersted in the profits :P)
After that I read a bit about chaos theory and found out that its basically finding patterns called fractals in the data available. After that I came to know it is used in various fields as weather prediction and stock prices determination.

I just wanted to know how if anyone has an idea on how we can do stock forecasting using chaos theory.

Like, it will be great if someone can provide me with some example w.r.t chaos theory.

Comment: I traded stocks professionally for many years.  We used a lot of math (PDEs, statistics, linear optimization), but we never used anything like chaos theory.  It's an interesting topic, but I don't think you find a lot of money in it.  There are books out there on chaos theory as applied to the financial markets, but they don't actually explain how to make money.  Books never do!  If you had a secret formula, would you write a book about it?

Comment: You can't use chaos theory to predict stock prices. The fundamental tenet of chaos theory is 'prediction is hard, if not impossible'. To say that a system is chaotic means that there is a *deterministic* rule for its future evolution, but that small differences in initial conditions grow exponentially quickly over time - meaning that a tiny error in estimating the initial conditions renders your predictions useless sufficiently far in the future. So there are two questions: (i) do stock prices follow a deterministic rule (they don't) and only then (ii) if so, do they display chaos?

Comment: P.S. If you *really* want to test a series of stock market returns to see if they're chaotic, then the modified Kolmogorov 0-1 test may be useful, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1418).

P.P.S. I think your keyboard may be broken, as it is automatically appending a string of periods (..........) to all of your posts.

Comment: @Chris: wouldn't you clarify why prices do not follow the deterministic rule?

Comment: If prices followed a deterministic rule then whenever you observe the system state to be $x_i$ at time $i$, you would expect to see a very similar state $x_{i+1}$ at the next time. Accounting for measurement error, the difference $||x_{i+1}-x_i||$ will either be small and roughly constant (if the system is deterministic and regular), exponentially increasing with time (if it's chaotic) or randomly distributed (if it's stochastic), see [this paper](http://www.santafe.edu/media/workingpapers/91-07-029.pdf). I admit that it's possible that the 'state' of the financial system ...

Comment: ... follows some incredibly convoluted deterministic rule dependent on many factors other than prices, but I don't think that's a particularly helpful model as you'd never be able to extract such a rule from the data. Instead, a stochastic modelling approach is the way forward.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I believe you meant *fractals* rather than *fractules*. No, sorry. First of all, do not fully rely upon advises of guys who made 30%+ profit until you have seen exactly that they did it. Even if the owner of Quantum Fund will tell you that he earned 30%+ profit, you can trust him - but don't still rely upon his advises.

Fractals are objects which seems to be very natural, however I do not know if they already were described formally. Say, [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) is known to be a fractal, but given some set $A$ you cannot say that it is a fractal.

The nature of the fractal is the following: each part of it has the same structure as the whole fractal (or there is a subset of each part, no matter how small is this part, which has the same structure as the whole fractal). This idea was applied by Benoit Mandelbrot to describe the structure of [Elliot Waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott_Wave_Principle) - one of the most important tool in technical analysis of charts. Mandelbrot wrote about it in his [paper](http://www.elliottwave.com/education/SciAmerican/Mandelbrot_Article2.htm). The main hypothesis: there are several factors which influence the price, some of them more, some - less, but the structure (not the amplitude) of these influences is the same.

The other application can be seen in the fractal Brownian motion. This stochastic process is used to model the price movements. You can also be interested in this case in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70578/fractional-brownian-motion-and-laplacian).

Finally, I guess that there are methods to model the price movements with dynamical systems which have a chaotic behavior. E.g. Shiryaev in book "Essentials of stochastic finance" devoted one section to discuss the difference between time series based on chaotic (deterministic) processes and stochastic processes (see chapter "Dynamical Chaos Models").

That's what I know on the subject. I cannot provide a good example unless I put here a plot of some dynamical chaotic system to show that it *looks like* the price movements. If you make your question more specific, maybe I can write more.

P.S. You may also ask this question on http://quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Here is a personal opinion: I don't believe in any mathematical models for stock prices or derivates or other financial products.
But here is a possible connection of chaos theory to stock price modelling, I'll simply throw some buzz words at you:

If you have a dynamical system with a long time trend and short time "random noise influences", you can try to model this system with a stochastic differential equation. The famous Black-Scholes formula for option pricing is derived from a linear Ito stochastic differential equation. On a conceptual level, it combines the long time trend coming from fixed interest rates with the short time noise coming from day-to-day trading by many different agents, each having a small influence.

The expectation values of certain stochastic differential equations solve certain partial differential equations. The expectation value of an Ito process, for example, solves the Kolmogorov forward equation. This is also true for the equations that describe the classical flow of a fluid, the Navier-Stokes equations.

For a paper adressing this topic, see

- Peter Constantin, Gautam Iyer: "A stochastic Lagrangian representation of the 3-dimensional incompressible Navier-Stokes equations" ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511067)).

A first approximation of a weather forecast would need to solve the Navier-Stokes equations of the atmosphere of the Earth. This means that you could, in theory, use stochastic differential equations to do a weather forecast.

Both stochastic differential equations and partial differential equations describe systems with infinite many degrees of freedom. But it is possible to approximate these systems with systems that have a finite number of degrees of freedom, that is, by a system of ordinary differential equations. You can try to devise this approximation in such a way that the finite system captures some characteristic properties, like turbulence of solutions of the Navier-Stokes equations.

Here is a book devoted to this topic:

- Thomas Bohr, Mogens H. Jensen, Giovanni Paladin, Angelo Vulpiani: "Dynamical systems approach to turbulence".

This is somewhat related to the numerical approximation of PDE via [spectral methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_methods), but in this case the trick is to find the approximation that results in the best results concerning specific properties of the system that you are interested in.

So, in this sense chaos theory aka dynamical systems can be used as an approximation to PDE which describe the time evolution of the probability laws of stochastic processes, which are the most common modelling tool of quants, I guess (I'm not a quant).

Answer (score 0):

The rate of return being claimed seems rather high. i think markets are mostly at least weak form efficient in that there is no memory in prices or returns and each event is independent and therefore random. Most of the hard evidence for chaos in stock returns comes from Rescaled Range analysis and I am posting a link below which takes a very skeptical view of these results. Anyway, I think anyone who claims they can make that kind of returns you quoted are probably trying to sell you something.

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2448648